# Putting my app as an option in the default dialer

Tags: iphone, ios

I am making an application for a telecom company. What I need is that if my app is installed on an iPhone, then when the user is dialing a number to call someone, then iOS will show an option of my app in the default dialer, the way it does if Skype is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Open a tel: url in app delegate:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", numberToCall] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];
```

Comment: It won't work in the simulator because no dialer app. Try on the device.